# Using NextJS with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to build an app using Firebase and NextJS.
I have already done something using Firebase and React, but not yet with NextJS.
So I am likely to miss some important details in the setting process.

I have tried to follow some tutorials and documents I found on the net, but it is still not all clear.

Here is what I did:

I used this command to first create a NextJS app

```
% npx create-next-app@latest
```

Then I ran:

```
% firebase init hosting
% firebase deploy --only hostings
```

In *firebase.json*, I also changed the *public* key as follows:

```
"hosting": {
  // "public": "public",
  "public": "app",
}
```

and copied *index.html* to the *app* directory.

Below is my current situation. When I run this in the terminal:

```
% npm run dev
```

and then point my web browser to:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

The file *app/page.tsx* is reflected.

But pointing the web browser to:

```
https://myexampleapp.web.app/
```

The file *app/index.html* is reflected.

Obviously, something is wrong. I should be seeing the same thing in both cases, if I had done my settings properly.

Can someone with NextJS experience on Firebase spot what I must be missing and give me some tip to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Running NextJS on dev(`npm run dev`) is entirely different from deploying it. You need to run `npm run build` if you are planning on deploying it.
You will then find the build files in app/.next by default or any directory that you've configured.

After you run `firebase deploy`, firebase will deploy your build output only, not the development files (all the react components will be compiled into plain javascript for deploy). Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure how to make full use of your answer. I have tried a bit more and made a new post, hoping this will make it easier to give a precise answer. The new post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041218/cant-use-nextjs-with-firebase