# Can't use NextJS with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to build an app using Firebase and NextJS. I have already done several tests, all of them unsuccessful at this point.

Below is a detailed description of my last trial. I hope someone will be able to point out some mistakes I am making on the way.

Here is the sequence of what I did in the terminal, along with the results:

```
me@MyMac % npx create-next-app@latest
✔ What is your project named? … njsapp
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint with this project? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS with this project? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? … No
✔ Would you like to use experimental `app/` directory with this project? … Yes
✔ What import alias would you like configured? … @/* (Enter)
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/njsapp.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: app-tw 


Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next
- typescript
- @types/react
- @types/node
- @types/react-dom
- tailwindcss
- postcss
- autoprefixer
- eslint
- eslint-config-next


added 326 packages, and audited 327 packages in 14s

116 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created njsapp at /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/njsapp

me@MyMac % 
me@MyMac % cd njsapp

me@MyMac % firebase init hosting
    - Use an existing project
    - What do you want to use as your public directory? (Default)
    - Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
    - Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
✔  Wrote public/404.html
✔  Wrote public/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
me@MyMac % 

me@MyMac % firebase deploy --only hosting

=== Deploying to 'fbapp'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[fbapp]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[fbapp]: found 4 files in public
✔  hosting[fbapp]: file upload complete
i  hosting[fbapp]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[fbapp]: version finalized
i  hosting[fbapp]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[fbapp]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fbapp/overview
Hosting URL: https://fbapp.web.app
me@MyMac % 


me@MyMac % npm run dev

> njsapp@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
info  - VS Code settings.json has been created for Next.js' automatic app types, this file can be added to .gitignore if desired
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1058 ms (265 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 171 ms (265 modules)
```

After this is all done; I point my web browser to: https://fbapp.web.app. This is what I see:

[image]

Then pointing the web browser to: http://localhost:3000/. This is what I see:

[image]

I expected to see the same thing in both cases. What did I do wrong or what should I do that I did not do?

As an extra piece of information, this is how the file *next.config.js* looks:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase hosting is looking for your static files and finding none.

You can tell firebase where to find your static files in your `firebase.json` where `out` will be where nextjs will export out static files.

```
//firebase.json

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

To tell nextjs to export our static files to the `out` folder, we must configure the `next.config.js` file as shown below

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Now run `npm run build` so that nextjs can produce an `out` folder which contains the HTML/CSS/JS assets for your application.

Then `firebase deploy --only hosting` and your application will be successfully deployed.

Comment: I have made a few trials following your indications, all of them failed. You write 'export' in next.config.js and you write "out" in firebase.json. Is that really what you mean ? Or should it be the same in both ?

Comment: It should be export, they should not be the same. When you run npm run build, does it output an out folder with static files like index.html?

Comment: Also, are you in the correct project when you run "firebase use" in the terminal?

Comment: I do not run "firebase use" (as you can see in my post). Taking a close look at your previous comment I was finally able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your steps, if you look at the messages closely, you can see that firebase has created public/index.html. In this case the public directory is being used as the build output directory. Configure njsappapp/public as build output file by modifying `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: 'public',
}
```

You need to run `npm run build` . Then all the build files be added in the `public` directory.

After these steps, run `firebase init` and `firebase deploy` as you've done in the above snapshot. Then only you'll see the actual files in your website. Cheers!

Comment: I have made a first try to follow your advice, it is not working for now. I may be not writing next.config.js exactly as I should. The file already exists and has some contents. So I am not sure how to insert the lines you suggest. I updated my post to show the next.config.js file as it originally looks.

Comment: Please follow through this link: <https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/lets-deploy-a-next-js-app-with-firebase-hosting-e070b3aecd04>