# Connecting a Firebase/NextJS app to a realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, firebase-hosting

I have just set up a small app using Firebase and NextJS.

I now would like to use the realtime database that I have from this app.

What is the proper way to connect to it?

I have already used a realtime DB before, with React apps and others but never with NextJS.

I tried to follow some sample code I found on the net, but it did work as expected so I would like to know the proper procedure to follow for that.

Comment: The question is a bit vague; it states you *set up an small app using Firebase and NextJS*. So... it's set up? What more do you need? What is the question? Does the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) help?

Comment: What I need is to to know how to connect my realtime database to this app and make use of it.

Comment: I tried to follow the guide you suggest, but to no avail at this point. Many things are left unclear. Like: are we supposed to store the config in a particular file? with a specific extension? Is there something specific about a next.js app compared to a react app? How do we make use of this file. I tried to imitate what I have working in the case of a react app ... but it did not work.

Comment: There's quite a bit of information about setting up NextJS with Firebase - and there are a number of steps involved. Likely too long to post here as an answer. Take a look at [NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041218/cant-use-nextjs-with-firebase) and [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/deploying-next-js-app-to-firebase-functions-eb473791d79e) and see if those help.